# In the event of a 404 error, refresh the page only once in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I would like to see if there is any way to implement a counter or some solution that will make the page refresh only once upon the 404 event.

In line 90 of the code that I will share with you at the end I have the problem since a loop is formed with the 404 error and the page is refreshed indefinitely.

Line 90:

`} else if (this.status === 404) { location.reload(); console.log("Error 404")}`

Complete code:

```
this.refreshCover = function (songIt = '', artistIt) {
        // Default cover art
        var urlCoverArt = DEFAULT_COVER_ART;
        
                    
        // URL of proxy for lyrics Api CORS Allow Origin *
        var proxy_URL = PROXYURL;
        
        var itunes_api = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=';

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var coverArt = document.getElementById('currentCoverArt');
            var coverBackground = document.getElementById('bgCover');
            var backgroundDefault = 'img/background.jpg';
            
            
            // Get cover art URL on iTunes API
            if (this.readyState === 4) { 
                
                if (this.status === 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                
                var artworkUrl100 = (data.resultCount) ? data.results[0].artworkUrl100 : urlCoverArt;

                // Se retornar algum dado, alterar a resolução da imagem ou definir a padrão
                urlCoverArt = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? artworkUrl100.replace('100x100bb', '512x512bb') : urlCoverArt;
                var urlCoverArt96 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '96x96bb') : urlCoverArt;
                var urlCoverArt128 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '128x128bb') : urlCoverArt;
                var urlCoverArt192 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '192x192bb') : urlCoverArt;
                var urlCoverArt256 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '256x256bb') : urlCoverArt;
                var urlCoverArt384 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '384x384bb') : urlCoverArt;

                
                
                coverArt.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + urlCoverArt + ')';
                coverArt.className = 'animated bounceInLeft';
                
                // If song cover art = default cover art change background default              
                if(coverArt.style.backgroundImage == 'url("img/103-logo.png")') {
                    coverBackground.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + backgroundDefault + ')'
                } else  { coverBackground.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + urlCoverArt + ')'
                }
                
                          

                setTimeout(function () {
                    coverArt.className = '';
                }, 2000);
                
                                                                
                if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
                    navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
                        title: songIt,
                        artist: artistIt,
                        artwork: [{
                                src: urlCoverArt96,
                                sizes: '96x96',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            },
                            {
                                src: urlCoverArt128,
                                sizes: '128x128',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            },
                            {
                                src: urlCoverArt192,
                                sizes: '192x192',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            },
                            {
                                src: urlCoverArt256,
                                sizes: '256x256',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            },
                            {
                                src: urlCoverArt384,
                                sizes: '384x384',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            },
                            {
                                src: urlCoverArt,
                                sizes: '512x512',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                }
            
            } else if (this.status === 404) { location.reload(); console.log("Error 404")}
        }
    }   
        
                
        xhttp.open('GET', proxy_URL + itunes_api + artistIt + ' ' + songIt + '&media=music&limit=1.', true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
```

**COMPLETE CODE FIXED:** credits @F.Igor

```
this.refreshCover = function (songIt = '', artistIt) {
        // Default cover art
        var urlCoverArt = DEFAULT_COVER_ART;
        
                    
        // URL of proxy for lyrics Api CORS Allow Origin *
        var proxy_URL = PROXYURL;
        
        var itunes_api = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=';

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var coverArt = document.getElementById('currentCoverArt');
            var coverBackground = document.getElementById('bgCover');
            var backgroundDefault = 'img/background.jpg';
            
            
            // Get cover art URL on iTunes API
            if (this.readyState === 4) { 
                
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    
                    var artworkUrl100 = (data.resultCount) ? data.results[0].artworkUrl100 : urlCoverArt;

                    // Se retornar algum dado, alterar a resolução da imagem ou definir a padrão
                    urlCoverArt = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? artworkUrl100.replace('100x100bb', '512x512bb') : urlCoverArt;
                    var urlCoverArt96 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '96x96bb') : urlCoverArt;
                    var urlCoverArt128 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '128x128bb') : urlCoverArt;
                    var urlCoverArt192 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '192x192bb') : urlCoverArt;
                    var urlCoverArt256 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '256x256bb') : urlCoverArt;
                    var urlCoverArt384 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '384x384bb') : urlCoverArt;

                    
                    
                    coverArt.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + urlCoverArt + ')';
                    coverArt.className = 'animated bounceInLeft';
                    
                    // If song cover art = default cover art change background default              
                        if(coverArt.style.backgroundImage == 'url("img/103-logo.png")') {
                            coverBackground.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + backgroundDefault + ')'
                        } else  { coverBackground.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + urlCoverArt + ')'
                        }
                        
                                  

                        setTimeout(function () {
                            coverArt.className = '';
                        }, 2000);
                
                                                                
                        if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
                            navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
                                title: songIt,
                                artist: artistIt,
                                artwork: [{
                                        src: urlCoverArt96,
                                        sizes: '96x96',
                                        type: 'image/png'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        src: urlCoverArt128,
                                        sizes: '128x128',
                                        type: 'image/png'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        src: urlCoverArt192,
                                        sizes: '192x192',
                                        type: 'image/png'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        src: urlCoverArt256,
                                        sizes: '256x256',
                                        type: 'image/png'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        src: urlCoverArt384,
                                        sizes: '384x384',
                                        type: 'image/png'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        src: urlCoverArt,
                                        sizes: '512x512',
                                        type: 'image/png'
                                    }
                                ]
                            });
                        }
            
                    localStorage.setItem("is_retry",'0'); // reset variable retries  
                } else if (this.status === 404) { 
                    console.log("Error 404"); // console before refresh
                     if (localStorage.getItem("is_retry")!='1') {
                         localStorage.setItem("is_retry",'1'); // mark retry
                         location.reload(); 
                     }
                            
                    }
            }   
        }   
                        
        xhttp.open('GET', proxy_URL + itunes_api + artistIt + ' ' + songIt + '&media=music&limit=1.', true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
```

Comment: 404 ERROR means the URL you are looking for does not exists. In your case page will be reloaded and same response (404) you will get which create infinite loop.

Comment: I know that, that's why I'm trying to find a solution.

Comment: One possible solution. Ask user to refresh browser manually

Comment: If cover image not found then send a default image.

Comment: Let me explain better, if the image is not found in iTunes, the API returns an `result 0`  which means that it cannot find the image, but always with status 200. If found it returns `result 1`. But in some cases, which are not many, the 404 error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve that easily in your front end. Once the page is refreshed, the state is reset. You can do this in your backend, where for every 404 response, you would need to store an identifier (user IP), 404 details, and a timestamp. For every 404 response, you would check the current user IP, if there is a record stored for another error within a defined timeframe.

Seems to complicate. Too much overhead. The easier way, repeat the request if it is not valid, and refresh your data rather than reloading the users page.

```
if (!makeRequest()) {
    makeRequest();
}

function makeRequest() {
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var coverArt = document.getElementById('currentCoverArt');
        var coverBackground = document.getElementById('bgCover');
        var backgroundDefault = 'img/background.jpg';
        // Get cover art URL on iTunes API
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                var artworkUrl100 = (data.resultCount) ? data.results[0].artworkUrl100 : urlCoverArt;
                // Se retornar algum dado, alterar a resolução da imagem ou definir a padrão
                urlCoverArt = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? artworkUrl100.replace('100x100bb', '512x512bb') : urlCoverArt;
                var urlCoverArt96 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '96x96bb') : urlCoverArt;
                var urlCoverArt128 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '128x128bb') : urlCoverArt;
                var urlCoverArt192 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '192x192bb') : urlCoverArt;
                var urlCoverArt256 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '256x256bb') : urlCoverArt;
                var urlCoverArt384 = (artworkUrl100 != urlCoverArt) ? urlCoverArt.replace('512x512bb', '384x384bb') : urlCoverArt;
                coverArt.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + urlCoverArt + ')';
                coverArt.className = 'animated bounceInLeft';
                // If song cover art = default cover art change background default              
                if (coverArt.style.backgroundImage == 'url("img/103-logo.png")') {
                    coverBackground.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + backgroundDefault + ')'
                } else {
                    coverBackground.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + urlCoverArt + ')'
                }
                setTimeout(function() {
                    coverArt.className = '';
                }, 2000);
                if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
                    navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
                        title: songIt,
                        artist: artistIt,
                        artwork: [{
                                src: urlCoverArt96,
                                sizes: '96x96',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            },
                            {
                                src: urlCoverArt128,
                                sizes: '128x128',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            },
                            {
                                src: urlCoverArt192,
                                sizes: '192x192',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            },
                            {
                                src: urlCoverArt256,
                                sizes: '256x256',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            },
                            {
                                src: urlCoverArt384,
                                sizes: '384x384',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            },
                            {
                                src: urlCoverArt,
                                sizes: '512x512',
                                type: 'image/png'
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                }
            } else if (this.status === 404) {
                console.log("Cover art not found: 404")
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your kind response and the time you have taken to provide me with a possible solution. I honestly find this process very cumbersome in my particular case.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:** credits @F.Igor

```
//code for normal / successful case
// ...
localStorage.setItem("is_retry",'0'); // reset variable retries 
                        
} else if (this.status === 404) { 
    console.log("Error 404"); // console before refresh
    if (localStorage.getItem("is_retry")!='1'){
         localStorage.setItem("is_retry",'1'); // mark retry
         location.reload(); 
    } else {
        //What to do if it has already been retried? message, notice, etc
    }
```